# Resolve design patterns in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, promise

For simplicity, let's say I am building a currency convertor app which uses data from a third party API. Rather than using the raw data return by the API I'd like to format it and then store it in a factory and eventually in the local storage.

I am using the resolve function to fetch the data:

```
.state('app.convertor', {
  url: '/convertor',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/convertor.html',
      resolve: {
        xe: ['RatesService', function (Rates) {
          return Rates.get()
        }]
      },
      controller: 'ConvertorCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

My services look like the following code. I know this doesn't work but it describes what I'd like, i.e. a service which returns the same type of data no matter whether I fetch it from an API or simply from my service:

```
.factory('RatesService',
  ['$http', 'localStorageService',
  function ($http, localStorage) {
    var xe = {}
    var lastUpdate

    function isOutdated (date) {
      return Date.now() < date + 1000 * 60 * 60 
    }

    return {
      get: function() {
        // Check if I already have some data and if it's still up to date
        if (lastUpdate && !isOutdated(lastUpdate) && xe.length) {
          return xe
        }

        // Check if I have previously saved some data in my local storage
        var _xe = localStorage.get('xe')
        if (_xe && !isOutdated(_xe.lastUpdate)) return _xe.xe

        // If don't have any data, 
        $http.get('/some/third/party/api').then(function (data) {
          data = data.data

          // ********************************
          // Some work here on my data
          // ********************************

          // Save my data in the factory / local storage for future use
          xe = data
          lastUpdate = Date.now()
          localStorage.set('xe', { xe: xe, lastUpdate: lastUpdate })

          return xe
        })
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Obviously, due to my asynchronous call, if I don't have any data, `xe` is `undefined` in my controller. Is there a way, I could encapsulate all this logic in my service, to get the exact same data on the controller side no matter wether I previously fetched the data or not and still use the resolve function?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You should `return` the promise you're creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `$http.get` to make your code working, as returning `$http.get` will return a promise from `get` function of a service, and when that gets resolved it will return data using inner return statement.

```
return $http.get('/some/third/party/api')
```